# Z_STREAM_ERROR return from zlib compress() STM32

Tags: c++, arduino, compression, stm32, zlib

I'm new with `zlib` library and C++. So, I have function to compress `char` and using `compress()` or `compress2()` on STM32.

I tried with sample code without compiling on STM32,  it worked! But, when I compile to STM32, it always returns (-2) or `Z_STREAM_ERROR`. When I print the result, it only prints the first `byte`. I have free memory left around 6 kb on the device. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Note: on `zconf.h`, I already lower the number of `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` to `1` and `MAX_WBITS` to `5`.

```
char* compressPayload(char* payload, char* outComp) {
  Serial.println(payload);
  //uLong comprLen = sizeof(outComp);

  int ReturnCode;
  uLong Length = (uLong)strlen(payload)+1;
  uLong comprLen = compressBound(Length);

  ReturnCode = compress((Bytef *)outComp, &comprLen, (const Bytef*)payload, Length);
  Serial.println(ReturnCode);

  return 0;
}
```

Function call on main:

```
char jsonNewData[300] = "{\"serialNumber\":\"123456\",\"msg\":\"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001\"}"; 
char jsonNewDataComp[200];
compressPayload(jsonNewData, jsonNewDataComp);
```

Comment: You understand that `sizeof(outComp);` is the size of a pointer, and not the size of what it points to, *right* ? The `comprLen` argument should be the size of the target compression buffer (i.e. where the compressed data is to be written) on entry, and should be *at least* `compressBound(Length)` in capacity. Frankly, the size of the target buffer should be one of the arguments to `compressPayload` as in/out, and if undersized compared to `compressBound(Length)`, the compression should be aborted and appropriate error handling should ensue.

Comment: @WhozCraig I already edited as your suggestion but still facing the same result. Always return (-2). Is there any other anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After days looking into it, the cause is from memory usage for buffering (I only have `5kb` free memory left, CMIIW).

On `deflate.c`, I found this:

```
if (memLevel < 1 || memLevel > MAX_MEM_LEVEL || method != Z_DEFLATED ||
        windowBits < 8 || windowBits > 15 || level < 0 || level > 9 ||
        strategy < 0 || strategy > Z_FIXED || (windowBits == 8 && wrap != 1)) {
        return Z_STREAM_ERROR;
}
if (windowBits == 8) windowBits = 9;  /* until 256-byte window bug fixed */
```

As mentioned above, on `zconf.h`, I already lower the number of `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` to `1` and `MAX_WBITS` to `5`. But looks like the minimum of `MAX_WBITS` is `8` (even `9`).

Is there any other option for strict memory usage for zlib?

Comment: An answer is not a place for a question. Ask a new question.

Comment: @Mark Adler okay thank you Mark. Here's my new question > [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617969/zlib-with-small-memory-usage)