# ZLIB with small memory usage

Tags: c++, embedded, zlib

I'm working on embedded device (STM32) with < `5kb` free FLASH memory left. I'm trying to compress `string` with zlib library.
I created function [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461714/z-stream-error-return-from-zlib-compress-stm32/) and it returns `-2` (`Z_STREAM_ERROR`).

What I did:

- On `zconf.h`, I changed value of `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` to `1` and `MAX_WBITS` to `5` to lower memory usage. But i still returns `-2` (`Z_STREAM_ERROR`).

Then I found this On `deflate.c` which I cannot lower `MAX_WBITS` less than `8`:

```
if (memLevel < 1 || memLevel > MAX_MEM_LEVEL || method != Z_DEFLATED ||
        windowBits < 8 || windowBits > 15 || level < 0 || level > 9 ||
        strategy < 0 || strategy > Z_FIXED || (windowBits == 8 && wrap != 1)) {
        return Z_STREAM_ERROR;
}
if (windowBits == 8) windowBits = 9;  /* until 256-byte window bug fixed */
```

Then I set it to `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` to `1` and `MAX_WBITS` to `8` but when I try to compile it always returns `region FLASH overflowed by 15960 bytes`. Looks like I run out of memory.

Then I tried another example:

- Follow with [zpipe.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zpipe.c) sample with defined `CHUNK` to `1024`.

Result still the same, `region FLASH overflowed by 15960 bytes`.
Is there any other way to do it with FLASH memory only `5kb` left?

Note:

- RAM is also `5kb` left.

Comment: When you say "with < 5kb free memory left", do you mean the RAM or the FLASH? If it's the FLASH you have to remember that the library itself will take up space with its code. If it's RAM then remember that the compression and decompression algorithms will use in-memory buffers for the internal data, as well as the memory needed for the compressed/decompressed string. In both cases you probably waste more space than you save.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it FLASH memory. Sorry i will edit the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so it's `5kb` after compiled the zlib function and library. But it failed with `FLASH overflowed` when I set `MAX_MEM_LEVEL` to `5` and `MAX_WBITS` to `8` (when I set both to `1` it compiled successfully with 5kb left free memory) but it always returns `-2` (`Z_STREAM_ERROR`) which explained above.

Comment: The values you try to change affect the compression algorithms and their **RAM** usage, not the static code size of the library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you have any suggestion with this condition?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the linker map file to see when and where the unexpected 20k FLASH might be used (you claim you have 5k free, and then you go 15k over, which is a total of 20k). Also, the zlib error is something you get at run-time, while the FLASH overrun is something you should be getting at build-time. You seem to have two different problems which you mix.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is the exact compile error `.text will not fit in region FLASH` I don't know what it means but it has a lot of `.text` in map file.

Comment: `.text` is the segment for the actual code, as well as all constant values (like string literals). The error you get says that you have too much code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did take a look. I tried to 'larger' device memory just to see if it compile. Looks like zlib needs at least `20kb` reserved memory to compile successfully. Is there any other way to reduce it?

Comment: `region FLASH overflowed by 15960 bytes` looks like a linker error, and is little to do with the code you have included, and more to do with size of the library.  It is what it is, but you may gain something by using compiler optimisation if you are not doing so already.

Comment: The values you are adjusting relate to the RAM usage, not the code space which is your problem here.  However the section on "Memory Footprint" here https://zlib.net/zlib_tech.html suggests that it cannot be dome in 5Kb RAM in any case.  Code optimisation done not generally impact data space usage, so even if you get it to fit, it is unlikely to be able to run.  Is the memory used statically allocated?  Last I used Zlib it used dynamic memory allocation internally.  How much heap have you allocated (if any); can you reduce the heap to make space for larger static allocation?

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I'm using static memory allocation for other purposes. I haven't tried reduce the heap to make more space. Maybe I will try it later. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @Clifford I need to edit those memory footprint notes, since they don't include the fixed amount of storage needed for the deflate data structure. That becomes significant when trying to minimize the footprint.

Comment: @MarkAdler : but presumably only makes the memory usage higher?  Until he can fit the code, the RAM usage is academic, but similarly if there is insufficient RAM working hard to make the code fit is pointless.  Good to have input from the author though - thanks.

Comment: @Pnzy : If you are using GCC, then most likely the heap size is set dynamically to use all available space after static allocation, so my point is academic.  In the Keil ARM MDK toolchain the heap is set to a fixed value regardless of static allocation, so you will get a linker error if the heap+static+stack allocation exceeds available memory.  However in this case it is the Flash ROM that you have run short of, so it is largely academic.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, that was my point, since that technical information page previously indicated that deflate _could_ be done with 3K of memory. I have now corrected that page to add the constant overhead of 6K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The minimum amount of RAM required by deflate is 9K. You might try a different compressor, such as [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4).

The deflate code itself compiles to 33K on my machine (x86_64 ISA), with speed optimization. I tried compiling with aggressive space optimization, which got it down to 25K.

Comment: Looks like it's dead end for my case. Thank you for your suggestion. I will mark the answer.

Comment: Is it the same with `compress` or `compress2` function?

Comment: Yes. Those functions use deflate.

Comment: Alright thank you

Comment: @Pnzy There is possibly scope for improving the existing code to allow space for this - that is to look at the problem holistically.  Rather than changing the zlib to make it fit, change your existing code to _allow_ zlib to fit.  However you need to improve both code size and RAM usage, and RAM usage is a matter of code/algorithm/data-structure efficiency and cannot be resolved by compiler optimisation.